# Proving basic properties of $\mathbb{C}G$-modules

Tags: modules, representation-theory

Is my following proof correct?

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\mathbb{C}G$ its group algebra. Let $\phi:\mathbb{C}G\to\mathbb{C}G$ be a $\mathbb{C}G$-homomorphism.

$
i)$
Then there exists a $w\in\mathbb{C}G$ such that $\phi(r)=rw$.

$ii)$ Let $W\subset\mathbb{C}G$ be an irreducible submodule and choose $0\neq w\in W$. Then
$W=\{rw\colon r\in\mathbb{C}G\}$.

Proof of $i)$. Let $e$ be the neutral element in the group, define $w:=\phi(e)$. Then since $\phi$ is a $\mathbb{C}G$-homomorphism, we see that $$
\phi(r)=\phi(r\cdot e)=r\cdot\phi(e)=rw.
$$

Proof of $\textit{ii)}$. I want to prove that $\{rw\colon r\in\mathbb{C}G\}$ is a submodule of $W$. Since it is non-zero and $W$ is irreducible, it then follows that $W=\{rw\colon r\in\mathbb{C}G\}$. For showing it is a submodule, I wanted to use that $gW\subset W$ for all $g\in G$. Then, is it true that $rW\subset W$ for all $r\in\mathbb{C}G$ and why?

Answer (score 1):

$W'=\{rw\mid r\in\mathbb{C}G\}$ is a $\mathbb{C}G$-submodule: for any $w_1,w_2\in W'$, $r\in\mathbb{C}G$, we have $w_1=r_1w$ and $w_2=r_2w$ for some $r_1,r_2\in\mathbb{C}G$.  Then
$$
rw_1+w_2=rr_1w+r_2w=\underbrace{(rr_1+r_2)}_{\in\mathbb{C}G}w\in W'.
$$

Comment: Is $W'$ also a submodule of $W$?

Comment: It has to be, since $w\in W$.

Comment: But how do I know $rw\in W$ for $r\in\mathbb{C}G$? I only know that $gw\in W$ for group elements $g$.

Comment: $W$ is given as a $\mathbb{C}G$-module (more precisely, a $\mathbb{C}G$-submodule of $\mathbb{C}G$).  So for any $r\in\mathbb{C}G$ and any $\tilde{w}\in W$ we must have $r\tilde{w}\in W$.